# How to use async/await inside client component in Next JS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma, server-action

i have been working on this for a while and i can't even make it work. the issue is that i wanna pass a value to my server action for prisma from my state management context. but everytime i try to run my code it throws an error.

in my client component

```
"use client";
import { Products, columns } from "@/app/store/columns";
import { DataTable } from "@/app/store/data-table";
import { getData } from "@/lib/store/get-product";
import { useProductPagination } from "@/lib/store/product-pagination";
import React from "react";

async function StoreTable() {
  const { page, perPage } = useProductPagination();

  const data = await getData(perPage, page);
  return (
    <div className="w-screen  pr-4 sm:pr-8 md:pr-10 max-w-7xl mx-auto">
      <DataTable data={data} columns={columns} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default StoreTable;
```

and the server action i try to handle is

```
import { Products } from "@/app/store/columns";
import prismadb from "../prismadb";

export async function getData(perPage: number, page: number): Promise<Products[]> {
    const products = await prismadb.product.findMany({
      skip: perPage,
      take: page,
    });
  
    return products.map((product, i) => ({
      id: i + 1,
      name: product.name,
      description: product.description,
      category: product.category,
      origin: product.origin,
      sell: product.sellingPrice,
      purchase: product.purchasedPrice,
      amount: Math.random() * 100,
      status: product.status == "active" ? "active" : "inactive",
    }));
  }
```

but the error i'm facing is `Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding` 'use client' `to a module that was originally written for the server.`

what i'm trying to do is to implement pagination to my datatable and handle the page in prisma. but i have no ideawhat else i have to do.

so please Help me out here.

Answer (score 3):

with `client components` you can not call an awaited function directly (API Requests). So you should use `useEffect` to make things work without any problem.
Can you try this code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Products, columns } from "@/app/store/columns";
import { DataTable } from "@/app/store/data-table";
import { getData } from "@/lib/store/get-product";
import { useProductPagination } from "@/lib/store/product-pagination";
import React from "react";

function StoreTable() {
  const { page, perPage } = useProductPagination();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); // based on your data you should store it here in state

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await getData(perPage, page);
        setData(result);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [perPage, page]);

  return (
    <div className="w-screen  pr-4 sm:pr-8 md:pr-10 max-w-7xl mx-auto">
      <DataTable data={data} columns={columns} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default StoreTable;
```

Hope this will be helpful for you! Good luck :).

Comment: my getData function is using prismaClient. and when i try to run it throws an error `Error fetching data: Error: PrismaClient is unable to run in this browser environment, or has been bundled for the browser (running in `unknown`).`

Comment: Did you try on another browser?

Comment: only in chrome. but i'm using searchParams now, and it works.

Comment: Try on another browser, maybe there are settings that you have to change!